# Attempting to use DbSet<TEntity>.Where() with EF7 and ASP.NET5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, coreclr

I have created a solution with an ASP.NET 5 MVC6 project, and a few class libraries. I am using Visual Studio 2015, and I am targeting "dnxcore50" and "net451".

In a class library I am writing the repository code with EF7. In a class I am attempting to use a few methods on DbSet<>. Namely ".Where(...)", ".Single(...)" and ".First(...)". These were available on the older version of .NET.

I am getting the following 2 errors:

> .NET Framework 4.5.1 error CS0012: The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>
> .NET Framework 4.5.1 error CS0012: The type 'Func<,>' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

It seems to build no problem in DNXCORE50 format, but not the full 4.5.1 version of .NET.

I have this in the project.json file:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516"
        ......
      }
    }
  }
```

I am targetting 1.0.0-rc1-final DNX SDK version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I finally think I managed to figure out why. If you create a class library, the project.json file has:

```
 "net451": { },
```

in the "frameworks" section. If I change this to:

```
"dnx451": { },
```

it then works. I'm not 100% sure if this has a knock on to anything else. But I'll use that for now.

Answer (score 1):

for additional answer we can still use net451 by adding "System.Runtime"

```js
"net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": ""
      }
    }
```